# How can I tell if a host is connecting via multiple spids using one application or running multiple instances of the application itself?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, sql-server-profiler, sp-who2

We trace our SQL Server activity for performance issues. Some applications, written in C#, look to have up to 50 individual spids connecting to the DB from a single machine. How can I distinguish if these spids are connecting from multiple individual instances of the application running on the same host machines, or single applications connecting with lots of spids?

Comment: `sys.dm_exec_sessions` exposes a `host_name` and a `host_process_id`. This info is supplied by the client side, so not suitable for security-sensitive purposes, but assuming you can trust your clients not to deliberately spoof this info it's usable.

Comment: Adding to @JeroenMostert's comment, each application instance on the same host will have a different process id. The client driver passes the OS PID.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can adapt this script to your needs

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_who2 (
       SPID INT,
       Status VARCHAR(255),
       Login  VARCHAR(255),
       HostName  VARCHAR(255),
       BlkBy  VARCHAR(255),
       DBName  VARCHAR(255),
       Command VARCHAR(255),
       CPUTime INT,
       DiskIO INT,
       LastBatch VARCHAR(255),
       ProgramName VARCHAR(255),
       SPID2 INT,
       REQUESTID INT)
INSERT INTO tbl_who2 EXEC sp_who2
SELECT      *
FROM        tbl_who2
WHERE       DBName = 'your_database'
ORDER BY    DBName ASC
DROP TABLE tbl_who2
```

See also [this](https://www.sqlmatters.com/Articles/sp_who2%20-%20filtering%20and%20sorting%20the%20results.aspx)

Comment: Thanks. I've been using a similar filter on sp_who2. It gives the the application name and the spid but no indication if it is the same instance of the application or different applications with the same connection string details.

Comment: Well it was worth a try